# How to specify a BlobTrigger binding so that container name is configurable?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I've an azure function with a blob trigger, but I'd like to be able to configure the container from which it is triggered with some configuration parameter that can be changed in the portal, without re-deploy the function.

At the moment the only way I found to define blob-trigger is to hard-code the container name in the function definition

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("photo-files/{name}",...
```

Is there way to do it in a more configurable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `%container%` syntax:

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("%container%/{name}",...
```

and then define the setting called `container` in application settings.